# cmake target-based conditional compile

Tags: c++, build, cmake, c-preprocessor

I have a large code base, which can compile both with and without MPI using a CMakeLists.txt written for Cmake 2.6; I want to refactor the CMakeLists.txt with target-based syntax (targeting CMake 3.9+).

In source files, this is enabled by C-preprocessor:

```
#ifdef USE_MPI
...
#endif
```

The current CMakeLists.txt uses `add_definitions(-DUSE_MPI)` to toggle preprocessor and `set(MPI_LIB "")` and `target_link_libraries( ... ${MPI_LIB} )` with `if` and `else` to do the conditional compilation for *each target*, and it gets messy quickly if number of target increases.

I want to

1. write `target_link_libraries( ... PUBLIC MPI::MPI ...)` for all targets without `if` and `else`.
2. have a single line to toggle preprocessor for all targets.

My idea is to create a dummy target if MPI is not found. Is it possible to create a dummy target in CMake?

Comment: The best way to go seems to be using *interface library* where the requirement is specified in a target and nothing get built. I will update an answer once I get it working.